# Angular2 post form query

Tags: angular

I'm trying to post a form to web API using post method.

The code is as below:

```
<li *ngFor="let borrower of borrowers">
  <div>{{borrower.id}},{{borrower.name}},{borrower.tenure}}</div>

<form [formGroup]="form">
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <label for="l_amt">Amount:</label>
      <input type="number" formControlName="amount" id="l_amt">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <label for="l_rate">Interest Rate (%):</label>
      <input type="number" formControlName="interest_rate" id="l_rate">
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!proposalForm.valid" (click)="submitProposalForm()">Send Proposal</button>
</form>
```

```html
submitProposalForm() {
    if( this.proposalForm.valid ) {
      this.service.submitProposal(this.proposalForm.value);
    }
  }
```

For every borrower, the form will collect amount & interest data from the user.

While posting to API, I want the JSON to be in this format

```
{ id={{borrower.id}}, amount=xx, interest_rate=xx, tenure={{borrower.tenure}} }
```

Since `id` and `tenure` are not part of the form JSON, how can we include then in the form JSON? Please help.

**IMPORTANT**: What I'm trying to ask here is how do I post ID and TENURE of the borrower along with form inputs AMOUNT & INTEREST_RATE?

Comment: That's not valid json also a form submit and json are not compatible unless you are posting as a string. You want to use proper binding to an object and then pass the object through the http service which (by default) will serialize the data to json format. Please follow the angular.js tutorial and how-to guides, they are great and found on their website.

Answer (score 0):

if you want a json in that format use your `formControlName` accordinly like this

```
<li *ngFor="let borrower of borrowers">
<div>{{borrower.id}},{{borrower.name}},{borrower.tenure}}</div>

<form [formGroup]="form">
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <label for="l_amt">Amount:</label>
      <input type="number" formControlName="amount" id="l_amt">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <label for="l_rate">Interest Rate (%):</label>
      <input type="number" formControlName="" id="l_rate">
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!proposalForm.valid" (click)="submitProposalForm()">Send Proposal</button>
</form>
```